# Exposing DataGrid in UserControl for Modification (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, user-controls

I'm fairly new in the WPF world and don't really now what to look for or how to ask this question so it propably is a duplicate but I can't really find a solution so I'm just gonna ask anyway.

I've got a custom UserControl that contains a DataGrid with an CheckBoxColumn.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WSConnect.WPF.Controls.CheckDataGrid"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="319.149" d:DesignWidth="530.699" Name="_checkDataGrid">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="DataGrid1">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="30">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="False"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="1 0 0 0" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Now I want to access the DataGrid from another UserControl/Window and add Columns/Rows and maybe also change some other stuff in the DataGrid.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WSConnect.WPF.Controls.Test"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WSConnect.WPF.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500">
<Grid>
    <local:CheckDataGrid>
        <!--This does not work-->
        <local:CheckDataGrid.DataGrid1>
            <!--Change stuff here-->
        </local:CheckDataGrid.DataGrid1>
    </local:CheckDataGrid>
</Grid>
```

How can I do something like this (preferable creating the DataGrid in the xml-code and not in code-behind)? Is it even possible? I've seen some stuff with ContentControl but I don't want to add stuff to my user control I want to modify a "predefined" DataGrid in another Window/UserControl.

Edit: 
The thing I want to accomplish is a reusable DataGrid which already has a CheckboxColumn and a checkbox in the header of this column. Also it should contain logic which checks the checkboxes in the column if the "header-checkbox" gets checked with the limitation that you can hand over some kind of action/boolean which validates for every single row if the appropriate checkbox can be checked.

Comment: You would have to expose that grid as a `DependencyProperty` on your UserControl to access it through xaml. Do you **really** need to have it inside of a `UserControl` though? These controls are available to be used in xaml in general terms, the only scenario where you would do that is to have custom display logic behind tha can't be achieved through styles and triggers, which is pretty rare.

Comment: It's not just the DataGrid that has to be exposed. I also need some Dependency Properties in the User-Control and I have to do some validation for the CheckBox-IsChecked. The basic idea is a DataGrid which has a Checkbox column as first column and also a checkbox in the header of the column which checkes/uncheckes all checkboxes in the Checkbox column. But there has to be some validation possibilities if the checkbox columns can be checked/unchecked through a routed event or sth like this. Can I archieve this through triggers?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve that with triggers and converters. If there is anyhting in the UI you can access it. Only for very specific scenarios you would use a custom control. If you give us the full story on what you want to do i.e. validation and what you need to validate with some conditions then I can produce an answer that will help you.

Comment: I need a DataGrid which has as first row a checkboxcolumn and also a checkbox in the header of this row (like I've already got in my code in the question). If the checkbox inside of the header gets checked/unchecked every checkbox in the checkboxcolumn should also get checked/unchecked. But there has to be a possibility to prevent the checking/unchecking for certain rows (e.g. some data is missing in the row so the "item" can't be used for the operation sb wants to perform with the selected/checked items). I already did this in my actual window/usercontrol but I did it depending on Properties.

Comment: Your bound data could take care of this, so instead of having UI caring about this your model could not allow the `IsChecked` property to be checked. Try to think about using your Model more in this case and then you will have an easy solutions without making much use of xaml side of things it will make the learning of WPF a lot easier. Once you're happy you can then dive deaper into XAML, BTW could you update you question with the last comment please.

Comment: I actually already solved this issue with the help of a ViewModel but I would like a more reusable solution so I don't have to create the same DataGrid multiple times in my project. That's also the reason I would prefer using an actual UserControl because I've got a lot of flexibility if I can create dependency properties.